# Namenode not coming out of safemode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to put some dummy file in HDFS, but it is showing foll. error:

> $ hadoop fs -put dummy.txt /user/hadoop
>   put: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create file/user/hadoop/dummy.txt. Name node is in safe mode.

For this I have tried the command:

`$ hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`

and tried to execute the previous hadoop put command . But it is again giving me the same error .

Name node is not coming out of safemode.

Any help on this please.

Comment: Check the status of the HDFS safemode using the get option and then put the file into HDFS.

Comment: I have tried get option and it shows: Safe mode is ON, even after running $ hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave.

Answer (score 2):

Try formatting your namenode .

```
 hadoop namenode -format
```

And then

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside docker Hadoop container bash shell, to create a file

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/test/
```